How to add webbingbrasil/filament-maps package into my fresh Laravel 11 site?
I tried to add the https://github.com/webbingbrasil/filament-maps package to my fresh Laravel 11 site, but I have some problems installing the package. I tried to install it by fixing the error with hints.
hoster@hoster-local:projectPath$ composer require webbingbrasil/filament-maps
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update webbingbrasil/filament-maps
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires webbingbrasil/filament-maps * -> satisfiable by webbingbrasil/filament-maps[v1.0.0, ..., v1.4.4, v2.0.0].
    - webbingbrasil/filament-maps[v1.0.0, ..., v1.4.4, v2.0.0] require filament/filament ^2.16 -> found filament/filament[v2.16.0, ..., v2.17.56] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^3.0-stable).

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require webbingbrasil/filament-maps:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require webbingbrasil/filament-maps:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
hoster@hoster-local:projectPath$ composer require webbingbrasil/filament-maps  -W
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update webbingbrasil/filament-maps --with-all-dependencies
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires webbingbrasil/filament-maps * -> satisfiable by webbingbrasil/filament-maps[v1.0.0, ..., v1.4.4, v2.0.0].
    - webbingbrasil/filament-maps[v1.0.0, ..., v1.4.4, v2.0.0] require filament/filament ^2.16 -> found filament/filament[v2.16.0, ..., v2.17.56] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^3.0-stable).

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require webbingbrasil/filament-maps:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require webbingbrasil/filament-maps:^2.1" if you know which you need.

hoster@hoster-local:projectPath$ composer require webbingbrasil/filament-maps:^2.0.0
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update webbingbrasil/filament-maps
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires webbingbrasil/filament-maps ^2.0.0 -> satisfiable by webbingbrasil/filament-maps[v2.0.0].
    - webbingbrasil/filament-maps v2.0.0 requires filament/filament ^2.16 -> found filament/filament[v2.16.0, ..., v2.17.56] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^3.0-stable).


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
hoster@hoster-local:projectPath$ composer require webbingbrasil/filament-maps:^3.0.0
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update webbingbrasil/filament-maps
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires webbingbrasil/filament-maps ^3.0.0, found webbingbrasil/filament-maps[v3.0.0-beta.1, v3.0.0-beta.2, 3.x-dev] but it does not match your minimum-stability.

In my composer.json I have "minimum-stability": "stable" and though the site is under de stahe now, I would not like to lower minimum-stability.
But how to install branch 2 correctly?

Which version do you want to install? version 2 or version 3 of this package?


Root composer.json requires webbingbrasil/filament-maps ^3.0.0, found
webbingbrasil/filament-maps[v3.0.0-beta.1, v3.0.0-beta.2, 3.x-dev] but it does > not match your minimum-stability.

This is your last error logs after your fixation.You are getting this error because composer by default uses stable as the minimum-stability, which means it won't install packages marked as beta or dev unless you change this setting.
You can resolve this issue by any of these two methods.
Method 1 :-
You need to adjust the minimum-stability(check the link) setting in your composer.json like this
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true

Then install the package using this command.
composer require webbingbrasil/filament-maps:^3.0.0

Method :- 2
The above method set the minimum-stability to dev globally. So if you don't want to set it globally then you need to install the package(i.e. webbingbrasil/filament-maps ) based on the exact version(check it here).
To do that you just need to set this into your composer.json like this
"require": {
    "webbingbrasil/filament-maps": "3.0.0-beta.2"
}

After setting this into the composer.json, do this
composer update 

OR
composer install

Try any of the above mentioned method, I believe it will resolve your issue.
N:B :- As per your stated concern(that you don't want to lower minimum-stability), you better to go with Method 2.
If you have any further query then please dont bother to ask.


filament-maps v1/v2: Only supports filament v2
filament-maps v3: Only supports filament v3. But it is still in beta.

This means "filament-maps is not officially compatible with filament v3."
You have to wait for the release of filament-maps v3.0.0 or use the beta version. Or use filament v2 and filament-maps v2.
